# What is the correct way to do a login screen in swift

Tags: ios, swift, authentication

I'm currently developing an iOS app with swift. And I need to make a Login screen.
What I want to do is: the first time the user opens the app, the login screen will be shown, but once the user is logged in (I know it because I save the server's session token in `NSUserDefaults` when the user logs in) the app will launch the main screen directly.
I'm wondering what is the correct way to achieve this (telling the app which screen to show). I tries 2 ways:

1. Loading the app at main screen, and if there is no token yet, present the `LoginViewController`. The problem I had with this way is that when I run the app it says that `LoginViewController`is not in the window hierarchy.
2. In the `AppDelegate` I check if there is a token and depending on the result I make `LoginViewController` or `MainViewController` the `rootViewController`. The problem with this is that it takes too long to change the `rootViewController` when changing it from `LoginViewController` to `MainViewController`.

Is there any better way to achieve this? which one is the best? Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you to start the application with the `MainViewController` and show the `LoginViewController` as a `modal` when you don't have a token. In this way you can show again the `LoginViewController` in other part of the application when for example the token will expire.

And...of course...do not store the auth token on nsuserdefault if you want have a little bit of security.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is the first option I've done, but xcode complains about `LogionViewController` not being at window hierarchy. `MainViewController`and `LoginViewController` are in different storyboards. What should I do to avoid this problem?

Comment: And thanks for the security advice! where should I store the token?

Comment: you need to show the `LoginViewController` after the `viewDidAppear` of the `MainViewController`. If you try to show it before you will receive that error.  The auth token should be stored on keychain.

Comment: @serenhopy i think you have not take Navigation controller Please can you try to embed your story board your start (first) viewcontroller  with the navigationcontroller.